# Get coordinate values from myLocationOverlay in Android

Tags: android, navigation, coordinates, routes, mylocationoverlay

I have an app that uses a map to show a certain, fixed, location. With the next update I'd like to show the route from the users current location to this fixed point. I already managed to get the users location via myLocationOverlay. 
As far as I see it I need to send the coordinates to Google Maps, receive a .kml file with the points and draw the route from that. How can I get the values for latitude and longitude from myLocationOverlay or is there a better way to do what I want to do?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getMyLocation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html#getMyLocation%28%29) from `MyLocationOverlay`. You then need to convert the `GeoPoint` into its respective degree for lat and long.

Here is a reference for [Geo.java](http://android-tools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/AndroidTools/src/com/honkentuber/android/Geo.java) that contains some of the function that you could use to convert the `GeoPoint` to its corresponding lat and longitude. In particular you want to use these two:

```
 public static Location toLocation(GeoPoint point) {
    Location result = new Location("");
    result.setLatitude(toDegrees(point.getLatitudeE6()));
    result.setLongitude(toDegrees(point.getLongitudeE6()));
    return result;
  }
```

And

```
  /**
   * Convert microdegrees to degrees.
   * @param degreesE6 Value in microdegrees.
   * @return Value in degrees.
   */
  public static double toDegrees(int degreesE6) {
    return (double) degreesE6 / E6;
  }
```